# When exactly did Moody and Tonks become close?

Tags: harry-potter

In Book 4, it's implied that Moody has been in retirement for some time. In Book 5, it's stated that Tonks only qualified to be an Auror a year ago. Even allowing for the three years that Auror training takes, it doesn't seem like there's too much room for overlap there.

Yet in Book 7, it's stated that Tonks had been "close to Mad-Eye, Harry knew, his favorite and his protégé at the Ministry of Magic." So how does that work out? In particular, when exactly did Moody retire?

Comment: Order of the Phoenix? I mean it's not that clear from Harry's perspective what they are doing, but we can assume that they are much more active behind the scene. And that might be the reason why they got that close.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin In Deathly Hallows it specifically said "at the Ministry of Magic," though...

Comment: I never had the impression that all members of the OotP were secrets. Yes their activity was, and some probably, but characters like Tonks or Moody were clearly part of it, at least from their friendships and relationships.

Comment: Well, yes, but we know Tonks was too young for the original Order and Moody was already retired by the time the Order rebanded. Clearly if Tonks had been Moody's "protégé at the Ministry of Magic," this occurred outside of merely their mutual membership in the Order.

Comment: Where is it implied exactly that Moody has been retired for some time? He may only have gone into retirement a few months before _GoF_ starts, for all we know. Isn't the only thing that's said that he's become even more paranoid since retiring?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  Good point. I always seemed to have the impression that Moody retired shortly after Voldemort's downfall and the subsequent clean-up, but do the books give an actual time range on when exactly Moody retired? I'll add that into the question to see if anyone can check up on that.

Comment: @BolteAltamont I would say it's at least _implied_ somewhat that he didn't retire that early. In the memory of Karkaroff’s trial (which was after Voldemort’s downfall and during the cleanup), he hasn't got his glass eye yet, so he must have stayed on after that. The glass eye seems to be a well-enough-known feature on him that he likely continued to work as an Auror with it for some time. Charlie Weasley says he met him as an Auror at the Ministry once when his dad brought him to work, but that could be any time. Bill seems to know of him the best, but that's only circumstantial too.

Comment: On the other hand, Sirius knows that he's retired, so it was likely not just a couple of months before starting at Hogwarts. There doesn't seem to be much to go by either way. :-/

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet To be fair, Sirius could have found out about Moody retiring through an edition of the Daily Prophet. While it isn't front page news, I imagine being locked up in a prison cell is boring enough to make an inmate read any newspaper he/she finds from cover to cover. And we know Sirius does receive/borrow a copy of the Prophet every now and then (that's how he realized Pettigrew was alive). It's possible an article in one of those editions either mentioned Moody's retirement or mentions Moody in passing as an ex-Auror.

Comment: Moody seems like the type that never goes fully into retirement though

Comment: @ʀᴇᴅ_ᴅᴇᴠɪʟ226 That is true, good point. Even after he got out of Azkaban, he steals newspapers in dog form, so any casual mention there (like the one at the start of _GoF_) would tip him off.

Comment: Paraphrasing the quote from Stone (as I don't have the books to hand): "There are some things that you can't go through without becoming close friends and knocking out a 30-foot tall mountain troll is one of them." Harry, Ron and Hermione become good friends after two months after sharing near-death adventures. No doubt Moody and Tonks also had their fair share of action that drew them together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### They probably weren't Aurors together

Tonks does say that she only qualified to be an Auror a year ago.

> 'Yeah,' said Tonks, looking proud. 'Kingsley is as well, he's a bit
> higher up than me, though. I
> only qualified a year ago. Nearly failed on Stealth and Tracking. I'm
> dead clumsy, did you hear
> me break that plate when we arrived downstairs?'
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

A year relative to what?

This when the Order of the Phoenix picks Harry up to take him to
Grimmauld Place. This is probably on the 5th of August:

> Otherwise, the Dursleys kept well clear of his bedroom. Harry couldn't
> see the point of forcing his company on them; another row would
> achieve nothing except perhaps make him so angry he'd perform more
> illegal magic. So it went on **for three whole days**.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

and

> That he did knowingly, deliberately and in full awareness of the
> illegality of
> his actions, having received a previous written warning from the
> Ministry of
> Magic on a similar charge, produce a Patronus Charm in a
> Muggle-inhabited
> area, in the presence of a Muggle, **on the second of August** at
> twenty-three
> minutes past nine, which constitutes an offence under Paragraph C of
> the Decree
> for the Reasonable Restriction of Underage Sorcery, 1875, and also
> under
> Section 13 of the International Confederation of Warlocks' Statute of
> Secrecy.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

"A year ago" probably means roughly a year ago. If the Ministry Auror training program operates on approximately the same schedule as Hogwarts, Tonks probably qualified in June, or about 14 months prior. Regardless, Moody must have been retired by September 1 of the previous year, when the train left for Hogwarts,  meaning that their tenure at the Auror office could only have overlapped by about two months, and that assumes that Tonks graduated somewhat over a year previously.

### Moody probably mentored Tonks during her training

Two months seems insufficient for someone to be established as another's "protégé."

However, the period of Auror training is three years, meaning Moody could have mentored Tonks for nearly that period before retiring. Three years is more than enough time for her to be his protégé, especially if her recognized her talents early on. Moody could easily have retired during the summer before Harry's fourth year; there is little information to suggest otherwise.